# Using async in a promise because of db-calls. How can I fix this antipattern?

Tags: javascript, function, firebase, ecmascript-6, promise

I have a Firebase Function which sends back data from databases. The problem is sometimes I have to return data all of 3 collections, sometimes only need from 1 and sometimes 2 of them. But this is an antipattern. How can I improve my code?

Right now I'm creating a function, which returns a promise, in which I'm using await for getting db values and this is wrapped in try{} block.

```
module.exports.getList = (uid, listType) => new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
let returnValue = [];
try {
    if (listType.contains("a")) {
        const block = await db.collection('alist').doc(uid).get();
        returnValue.push(block);
    }
    if (listType.contains("b")) {
        const like = await db.collection('blist').doc(uid).get();
        returnValue.push(like);
    }
    if (listType.contains("c")) {
        const match = await db.collection('clist').doc(uid).get();
        returnValue.push(match);
    }
} catch (e) {
    return reject(e);
}
return resolve(returnValue);});
```

How should I modify this snippet in order to not be an antipattern? Or is it not because of the try-catch block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the `getList` function `async` instead, without `new Promise` or `try`/`catch`:

```
module.exports.getList = async (uid, listType) => {
  const returnValue = [];
  if (listType.contains("a")) {
    const block = await db.collection('alist').doc(uid).get();
    returnValue.push(block);
  }
  if (listType.contains("b")) {
    const like = await db.collection('blist').doc(uid).get();
    returnValue.push(like);
  }
  if (listType.contains("c")) {
    const match = await db.collection('clist').doc(uid).get();
    returnValue.push(match);
  }
  return returnValue;
};
```

Calling it will return a `Promise` that rejects with an error if there's an asynchronous error, or it will resolve to the desired array.

Note that unless there's a good reason to `await` each call in serial, you can use `Promise.all` instead, so that the requests go out in parallel, and make the code a lot more concise in the process:

```
module.exports.getList = (uid, listType) => Promise.all(
  ['alist', 'blist', 'clist']
    .filter(name => listType.contains(name[0]))
    .map(name => db.collection(name).doc(uid).get())
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!